# Is NEXUS going to start accepting applications now that the US-Canada border is open?

Tags: nexus

On August 9th 2021, Canada reopened the US land border for "non-essential purposes". However the [official NEXUS page](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/services/covid/changes-changements-eng.html) still says applications are closed:

> NEXUS and FAST enrollment centres remain temporarily closed as long as COVID-19 border restrictions are in place.

Have there been any news or press releases on this subject, now that border restrictions are winding down? If NEXUS reopens soon, I'll hold off on applying for a Global Entry card and get the NEXUS instead. If it doesn't any time soon, I'll just pay for a Global Entry application.

Comment: I'd just note that even if they reopen the enrollment centers soon that doesn't necessarily mean they'll start accepting new membership applications right away. Renewal applications also require interviews at those same centers (or via Zoom with the same people that man those centers) and they have a 17 month backlog of already-paid-for renewals that they'll need to clear somehow.

Comment: The US land border is still closed to non-essential traffic.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168276/1810 seems to say otherwise

Comment: Can't you apply here? https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Canada->US land border is still closed for non-US residents.  US->Canada open for US and CDN both.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, [NEXUS enrollment centers in the United States are now scheduling appointments for interviews beginning  November 29, 2021](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/location-eng.html). Locations in Canada are still closed for appointments at this time.

At this point it isn't as busy as I thought it might be, perhaps because of the lack of publicity. They've been scheduling appointments for the first 3 months for a few weeks now and, while some locations are fully scheduled, others still have February, and even January, slots available.

Comment: But without the Canadian side the Nexus application is pointless?

Comment: @JonathanReez, There are both Canadian and US officers present (perhaps some of them virtually, now?) at NEXUS enrollment centers no matter which side of the border the office is on, it is this which distinguishes them from regular Global Entry enrollment centers. That the linked-to page announcing the opening is a CBSA page suggests they are okay with whatever the arrangement is.