# Travel to Canada by car. Vaccine requirements for 13 and under?

Tags: canada, us-citizens, covid-19, children, vaccinations

We are US citizens family of five. Both me and my wife have been vaccinated for covid 19 with pfizer.  We can bring proof via our vaccine cards showing both doses.  I have three children a 13 year old, a 7 year old, and a six year old.

If we are coming from michigan into canada do my kids need to be vaccinated?  Do any of us need proof of negative covid 19?  Plan is to travel to Canada to meet family at the end of December of this year.

We do not plan to stay in canada at all. We will visit windsor for about 6-8 hours and return back to Michigan. So there is absolutely no plan to stay any days.

Comment: Pfizer is now emergency-approved for 5-11 year-olds. My 9 year olds will get their first shots tomorrow and 2nd ones end of November. We plan to travel at the end of December but domestically only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@KateGregory's answer discusses vaccination in detail, but not proof of negative COVID tests.  As far as I know, everyone in your group needs (since everyone is older than 5) to show proof of a negative COVID test (PCR) taken within the previous 72 hours (see [link](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/covid-vaccinated-travellers-entering-canada#entry-vaccinated))

> Required to show a pre-entry molecular test
> Required to use ArriveCAN
> Required to take an arrival test if selected

There's a lot of grumbling about the negative COVID test requirement, so there's a chance it will be relaxed by late December, but those are the rules right now.

There's more on the nuts and bolts of testing in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169580/visiting-canada-from-europe-with-weekend-trip-to-the-us-will-we-need-testing).

---

**update** 8 Dec 2022: pre-entry tests are no longer required for *Canadians traveling to the US for < 72 hours* (see [here](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/flying-canada-checklist/covid-19-testing-travellers-coming-into-canada)), but AFAICT the requirement is still there for *US citizens traveling to Canada for a short time*.

Comment: This is good info. i just want to say that I answered about vaccine requirements because that was the question. If you want to list all the border crossing stuff I think you also still need to have a quarantine plan (this consists of knowing an address in Canada as far as I can tell) in case you are not exempted.

Comment: the OP did ask specifically about proof of covid test (second sentence of second paragraph) ...

Answer (score 14):

Children who are travelling with fully vaccinated adults are allowed in but must semi-quarantine.

[To be specific](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/covid-vaccinated-travellers-entering-canada):

- unvaccinated children under 12 years of age who are accompanying a parent, step-parent, guardian or tutor who qualified as a fully vaccinated traveller when they entered Canada. For the next 14 days, the children: must take pre-entry, arrival and Day-8 tests (unless under the age of 5); can’t attend school, camp or daycare;
  can’t attend large crowded settings, indoors or outdoors, such as an amusement park or sporting event; can’t take buses, subways, trains or other crowded transportation; must follow all the requirements in the children’s handout provided at the border
- Unvaccinated and partially vaccinated youth 12 to 17 years of age are subject to the 14-day quarantine, and all testing requirements for pre-entry, arrival and Day-8 tests, whether or not they are accompanied by travellers who qualify as a fully vaccinated traveller.

[I am pretty sure](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/exemptions#unvaccinated) "the 14-day quarantine" for your 14 year old is **not** the "avoid crowded stuff" the under-12's have to do but rather the "stay in your room and see no-one" that adults have to do. In other words, everyone over 12 is treated the same. Since you are aiming for end of December, I would suggest getting your 14 year vaccinated. There is time for both doses.

Comment: Im not sure i understand this answer. Maybe its late in the day. We planned on just visiting family in windsor and returning the same exact day. We did not plan to stay at all. Does that mean we have to quarantine for 14 days?

Comment: If your stay is less than 14 days, sounds by the guidance that you'd have to quarantine the entire time. The younger children would be able to stick to non-crowded settings and no public transit, but the oldest (13/14) would need to quarantine properly (no contact) for the duration.  Might want to consider vaccinating the oldest.

Comment: Lets assume my oldest one gets the vaccine. We only want to go for a few hours. We dont plan to go anywhere except my sister in laws house to visit them for potentially 6-8 hours. I have to return back to michigan the same day. Do we still need to quarantine?

Comment: @JonH if everyone is fully vaccinated and everyone in your car has a COVID test not older than 72 hours, then no, you won't have to quarantine. Vaccines are now available for under-12s too, so your 6 and 7 year olds can get them on schedule too.

Comment: If your oldest is vaccinated too then a day trip can work, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168276/is-a-day-trip-us-to-canada-currently-practical?rq=1 for logistics. At the moment the 11 and unders don't **have to ** be vaccinated even though they can.

Comment: @JonathanReez - Still does not answer my question fully.  I and my wife are vaccinated.  The plan is to have my 13 year old vaccinated.  I do not want my 6 year old and 7 year old vaccinated right now.  So those 2 will NOT be vaccinated.  We all plan to get a covid test 72 hours before going to canada as we need proof of covid 19 negative result.  So again I ask my question, We are only going for 6-8 hours to my sister in law's house.  Where I am getting confused is this 14 day quarantine.  I need to return back to the USA immediately on the same day.  Do we need to quarantine?

Comment: @JonH At present, [by the rules](https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/services/publications/diseases-conditions/fully-vaccinated-travellers-without-covid-19-symptoms-returning-canada.html), no.  But don't expect that to not change in the next eight weeks. Once vaccines are more broadly available for 5-12yr olds (which is happening *now*) it's likely that the requirements will change and you may no longer be allowed to take them across without a quarantine.  If you insist on not vaccinating your kids there will remain a risk that the rules will not be in your favour when you intend to travel.