# Crossing the border from Canada into the USA as a Canadian Citizen?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, covid-19, borders, canadian-citizens

Can’t seem to find solid information about this. I’m planning on crossing down to the states from Niagara Falls (Ontario) on December 31, and plan on being back inside Canada on January 3rd. Doing this using a rental car (Enterprise Rent a car). With the new Omicron restrictions, would I need to self isolate or pay for any tests for this short trip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that pandemic-related restrictions can change at a short notice and the Government of Canada advises to avoid non-essential travels at the moment.

### For your trip to the U.S.

Omicron has not yet changed land border requirements. If you are not a U.S. citizen or permanent resident, you may only travel across the land border  for a discretionary purpose if you are fully vaccinated and have acceptable documentation.

A negative test is not required at the moment.

Your destination in the U.S. may impose additional local and state requirements.

### For your return trip

As of December 21, 2021, at 12:01 am (EST), all Canadian citizens, permanent residents and registered Indians returning from short trips must take a molecular pre-entry test. The test must be taken **outside of Canada**. Previous short-trip (72-hour) exemption allowing pre-departure test in Canada **no longer applies.**

For possible testing options, see [Visiting Canada from Europe, with weekend trip to the US – will we need testing when going back to Canada?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169580/visiting-canada-from-europe-with-weekend-trip-to-the-us-will-we-need-testing/169588). You may need to arrange the test as soon as possible since many testing facilities may close or have modified hours during the holidays.

You may be randomly selected for arrival testing (mandatory but without charge) and have to self-swab within 24 hours of your entry into Canada, but if you have not been outside the U.S. or Canada during the past 14 days, you do not have to quarantine if you are fully vaccinated.

ArriveCAN remains necessary even if you are [fully vaccinated](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/covid-vaccinated-travellers-entering-canada). If you are not vaccinated, a 14-day quarantine is necessary.

Regardless of your vaccination status, if you present symptoms, you are required to isolate for at least 10 days and follow all applicable provincial public restrictions. **Foreign nationals with symptoms will be refused entry.**

Comment: What happens if a Canadian citizen shows up to a Canadian land port of entry without a pre-entry test?

Comment: @user102008 They are of course allowed to enter Canada. Upon entry they are then subject to provincial and federal public health restrictions, including mandatory testing and isolation. They will also possibly face fines up to $5000 with surcharges for violation of the Quarantine Act and emergency orders made under it, including the requirement to present a valid negative test. Provinces may have their own regulations and can open proceedings under public health laws.